# Why Is This Code Causing The Admin Bar to Disappear?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, terms, admin-bar

I have the following code:

```
function show_offering_categories() {
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'offering_category',
    'hide_empty'    => 1, // Yes
    'parent'        => 0, // Only top-level terms
) );
$content = '<div class="offer_cats"><ul>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $content .= "<li><a href='http://www.philcata.com/" . $term->taxonomy . "/" . $term->slug . "/'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>";
}
$content .= '</ul></div>';
return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'offeringcat', 'show_offering_categories' );
```

in a simple plugin (and previously in functions.php). When I pull up this page on my WP install, e.g.:

http://www.philcata.com/offering_category/

And then navigate to one of the pages linked to from this page, like the following:

http://www.philcata.com/offering_category/wordpress/

The admin bar disappears from the latter page.

Strangely, if I change to a different them and go directly to:

http://www.philcata.com/offering_category/wordpress/

The admin bar is visible...but if I then go back to:

http://www.philcata.com/offering_category/

And then forward again to:

http://www.philcata.com/offering_category/wordpress/

The admin bar is missing again!

I've tried this with GeneratePress and with Twenty Seventeen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: don't see how your code would affect the admin bar at all, perhaps there is a plugin you've added recently causing the conflict instead? try disabling all plugins and see if that makes a difference... (also note it's hard for others to help you track this as they are not logged in and cannot see an admin bar in any case!)

Comment: I had tried disabling all plugins with no luck! I suspect (but can't prove) that the issue was actually with my web host, who did a significant rewrite of their caching plugin and integration with CloudFlare around the same time these issues arose.